# iOS 9.3 on iPhone 5 (Night Shift option is unavailable)

Tags: ios, night-shift

I recently updated my iPhone 5 to iOS 9.3 and there is a new functionality introduced as "Night shift" option.

However it is not available on my iPhone 5
Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Can you please expand your question with more info about what you have tried? Also, a screenshot of Settings > Display & Brightness would be good.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error – it's because of the processing architecture. The iPhone 5 is an older model, and Apple isn't going to support 32-bit devices for Night Shift.